# batch files: using IF EXIST

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following batch file:

```
=================== exist-test.bat
@echo off
set pavtest=
if EXIST %programfiles(x86)%\AAA (
     set pavtest = AAA
     echo we have done the AAA test
) ELSE (
    if EXIST %programfiles%\BBB (
     set pavtest = BBB
     echo we have done the BBB test
    )
)
```

Suppose neither the AAA nor BBB folders exist. Then I'd think that the logic would be:

1. The first IF EXIST is false, so control transfers to ELSE
2. The second IF exist is also false, so we skip this branch too.

Instead, what happens on Win7 is that both echo statements are executed, and of course the value of pavtest at the end is BBB.

Can anyone explain why my logic is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Always best practice to use double quotes around any file paths you are using.  This protects spaces and special characters.  Also do not use spaces with in the `SET` command.  The space becomes part of the variable name and the value of the variable.

```
@echo off
set pavtest=
if EXIST "%programfiles(x86)%\AAA" (
     set pavtest=AAA
     echo we have done the AAA test
) ELSE (
    if EXIST "%programfiles%\BBB" (
     set pavtest=BBB
     echo we have done the BBB test
    )
)
```

Comment: `set pavtest=AAA` --> `set "pavtest=AAA"`?